# Where can i get the step by step expression for CMB anisotropy?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, cosmic-microwave-background

I never able to wrap my head around alm term used in expression [image]

If you know the expression, kindly explain but also give textbook references. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Any function on a sphere can be expanded as a linear combination of [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) $Y_{\ell m}$. The numbers $a_{\ell m}$ tell you “how much” of each spherical harmonic is needed. This is similar to a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) for decomposing any periodic function $f(x)$ into its sinusoidal “harmonics”.

Conceptually, the spherical harmonics are a [complete orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) for the infinite-dimensional [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) of functions on a sphere, in the same way that $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$  are a complete orthonormal basis for three-dimensional Euclidean vector space (and in the same way that $\cos{nx}$ and $\sin{nx}$ are a complete orthonormal basis for periodic functions in one dimension). The $a_{\ell m}$ are the *components* of $T$ in this basis.

One classic reference book for such things is *Methods of Mathematical Physics* by Courant and Hilbert.

The book or paper you referenced has a typo. They meant that the $a_{00}$ term measures the mean temperature. This is because the first spherical harmonic $Y_{00}$ is a constant over the sphere. The other terms represent angular fluctuations in temperature around the mean, on smaller and smaller angular scales as $\ell$ increases.

Comment: nice answer. +1. Of course I knew exactly that, but I couldn't have said it so clearly or succinctly.

Comment: Good answer sir, i got your point but i am asking for the mathematics behind it. And also textbook references for the expression.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh The mathematics is summarized in the first and second paragraphs, and a textbook reference is provided in the third. The relevant concepts to learn about are abstract vector spaces (including spaces of functions as infinite-dimensional examples), bases, orthonormality, and completeness. All of these are standard concepts in, say, a course on quantum mechanics. Have you studied QM yet? All these concepts are also involved in the classical mechanics of, say, a vibrating string. Did you learn about Fourier analysis then?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh *textbook references for the expression* An example of your expression is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Spherical_harmonics_expansion) (and surely also in Courant and Hilbert’s book). This part of the article also explains how to use the orthonormality of the spherical harmonics to *calculate* the $a_{\ell m}$ from the function $T$. This expansion has essentially nothing to do with temperature or the CMB, in case this was something you were wondering about. Any function on a sphere can be expanded like this.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh If you want to understand *why* the spherical harmonics are a complete orthonormal basis for functions on a sphere, and how they were discovered, then the relevant math is [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Liouville_theory) as applied to [Laplace’s equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) on a sphere. Courant and Hilbert probably covers this in detail. I’m sorry that I can’t say for sure; I used to have a copy but no longer do.

Comment: @RajdeepSingh if you are interested in physics more than in mathematics, then I recommend not getting down into the details of Sturm-Liouville theory. It suffices for a physicist to understand that the spherical harmonics are found by solving Laplace’s equation on a sphere, that they have an orthonormality relation, and that *any* function on a sphere (presumably subject to some continuity and differentiability conditions of little interest to most physicists) can be represented as linear combinations of them.

Comment: Alright sir thank you so much. I will find it in library.